# How to get specific word from string?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want specific word from particular string. Prefix word will never change.

I am trying to extract word from string. My logic is working for shell script. But when I'm trying to implement same logic for Jenkins pipeline script using groovy file, it won't work. Please help me out to solve this issue! Thanks in advance.

```
Input : var="<file name="abcd.txt" path="data/folder" site="stackoverflow" word="apple/fruit/www.yahoo.com" remote-branch="a.b.c" tags="bool"/>"
```

```
Output : "www.yahoo.com"
```

I want only "www.yahoo.com" in string. Note in string prefix word`(word="apple/fruit/)` will never change, but suffix word `(remote-branch)` can change.

I need solution for Jenkins pipeline method, where I am attaching groovy script and in groovy script, we can use shell script. But my shell script code is not working in Jenkins, where in shell script it is working fine.

Tried :

`echo $var | awk -F 'rword="apple\/fruit\/|"' '{print $1}'`

`echo $var | sed 's/.*word="apple\/fruit\/\(.*\)" .*/\1/'`

`echo $var | grep -oP '(?<=fruit\/).*(?=" )'`

But, I am getting this output of above tried commands:
`www.yahoo.com" remote-branch="a.b.c`

Please provide me solution using grep,awk,sed,cut for groovy style.

Again Thanks!

Comment: From the title, I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I updated my title.I explained my issue in description. Please help me.

Comment: `newVar=${var#*fruit}; echo ${newVar%% *}` ; returns `www.yahoo.com`  Good luck.